# What is the simplest way for me to use/sign the AWS Product Advertising API using Python?

Tags: api, web-services, signing, amazon-product-api

I have been banging my head against the wall trying different ways to properly sign my request so that I can make a retrieve price api call through the aws service.

Here is the call I am attempting to make:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingPriceInformation.html

After a while I decided it would be best to use an existing module if possible so I am trying to use:
https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth

However, when I try to change it to for use with the Retrieve Price request I am running into some issues. Is there a way to rework the following code or is there a better path forward that I should take?

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth

associate_tag = "IMA_associate"
access_key = "SLIGHTLYLESSSECRETKEY"
secret_key = "SUPERSECRETKEY"

t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

auth = AWSRequestsAuth(aws_access_key=access_key,
                       aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
                       aws_host='http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml',
                       aws_region='us-west-1',
                       aws_service='AWSECommerceService')

endpoint = 'http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml' \
    + '?AssociateTag=' + associate_tag \
    + '&AWSAccessKeyId=' + access_key \
    + '&IdType=ASIN' \
    + '&ItemId=B00KOKTZLQ' \
    + '&Operation=ItemLookup' \
    + '&ResponseGroup=Offers' \
    + '&Service=AWSECommerceService' \
    # + '&Signature=' + auth \
    + '&Timestamp=' + str(datestamp)


response = requests.get(endpoint, auth=auth)
print(response.content)
```

I really appreciate any help I can get on this ! Including just a point in the right direction, this is a bit out of my wheelhouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a very helpful Python module that let me solve the issue above.

https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api

This module makes it extremely simple to make Amazon api product calls. It is missing a few product characteristics that the api offers, but it was easy enough to add them to the project and I will be putting a pr in with all the new info so hopefully by the time anyone reads this it will be ready with access to all the information the api offers.